# unity3d model falling apart

Tags: unity, models

I found something I can't understand.
I'm only a beginner, so I thought I could use the CarController Scripts of the Car Demo for making a little driving game with different models.
[image: the Car demo]
I wonder why the colliders are sub-objects and the RigidBody has "Gravity-Enabled" without falling apart.
[image: my try to copy]
my model falls apart with the same configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to fix this is :

1. Remove the collider and rigidbody from the parent object.
2. Select all the children of your object that are part of the car
3. Give all these children Ridigbodies, and sphere/cube/capsule // generated colliders according to your needs. And make all the rigidbodies **kinematic**. That should keep them from pushing away each other, and "glue" them in a way.

You can still address the parent now, and use forces / translations on him correctly.

Comment: so I need to code the gravity?

Comment: A kinematic object is still affected by gravity, and all types of forces YOU apply, just not any other forces from collisions and contact

Comment: thanks, but sorry, can't upvote your answer yet

Comment: Sorry by the way, I was wronged, a kinematic object won't be affected by gravity, but since you added the kinematic rigidbodies the children, you can add a rigidbody to the parent of all objects, and make that one not kinematic.